# How can I add a new record to a database table and set the primary key value in Joomla, using JTable?

Tags: database, joomla, insert, jtable, record

I would like to add a new record to a database table in Joomla. I know how to do this with a simple sql query, but I would like to do it nicely using JTable (for correctly checking in and out). However, `JTable::store()` only adds a new record if the primary key is not set, otherwise it will try to update an existing record.

In code this is what I wanted:

```
$data = array( "module_id" => 222, "extra_param" => "hi" );

public function save( $data )
{
  $table = $this->getTable(); // Primary key = "module_id".
  $table->bind( $data );
  $table->check();
  $table->store();
}
```